# AdColony -showWithPresentingViewController: not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, adcolony

So I am trying to present an interstitial video ad from my viewController and I keep getting this error.

```
2018-01-03 20:54:52.936999-0500 MyApp[4786:1291385]
AdColony [Info] : Interstitial ad request succeeded in zone: zoneId

2018-01-03 20:54:53.452144-0500 MyApp[4786:1291248]
Warning: Attempt to present <ADCContainer: 0x11079d250> on <UIViewController: 0x10571fdf0> 
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The viewController that I am trying to present happens to be the rootViewController of my app, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. I initialize the viewController inside my appDelegate.

```
let vc = UIViewController()

window = UIWindow()
window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Any ideas why it won't present the AdColony ad?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was not working!

I needed to make sure that my app supported all orientations.